# SharePoint Designer: Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException was thrown. 0x80020009

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When the Web Page is opened using SharePoint DesignerXSLT List view that contains over one thousand of word documents below exception is thrown.

Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException was thrown. 0x80020009

[image]
Help in resolving this is greatly appreciated. Google results did not convey exact reason yet.

Thanks,

Comment: And this happens to all lists that have more than a 1000 documents or just this one?

Comment: Thanks for your response Eric. It happens for any view that has been created on the documents library that contains over 1100 documents. This appears to be the permissions related rather than number of documents. Further help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.